# Network request failed in React Native 0.15

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with fetch.

This is my code :

```
fetch("https://myUrl/myAPI", {method: "POST", headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Cache-Control": "no-cache"}, body:"myFirstVar=my+First+Var&mySecondVar=my+Second+Var"})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {status=responseData; this.setState((state) => {return {};})})
    .catch( (error) => {status=error; this.setState((state) => {return {};})})
    .done();
```

I have an error :

```
Network request failed
onload fetch.js:370
_sendLoad XMLHttpRequestBase.js:181
setReadyState XMLHttpRequestBase.js:171
...
```

Do you have a solution ?

I try my server with this :

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'myFirstVar=my+First+Var&mySecondVar=my+Second+Var' 'https://myUrl/myAPI'
```

I work with wireshark and I have the same request with my curl and with my fetch. I have the same problem on Android and iOS.

Comment: I had a similar issue where I had missed to URI encode parts of my data. Might that be your issue? For me, passing all my URL parameters through encodeURIComponent solved this issue.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. I deleted all my + and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Koes Bong I think it's the same problem with certificate. How did you solve your problem ?